# Python string to json

Tags: json, string, python-2.7, type-conversion

```
a1='[{"v1":"value"}, {"v1":"value"}, ]' 
b1=json.loads(a1)
```

Creates exceptions, BUT.

```
a2='[{"v1":"value"}, {"v1":"value"}]' 
b2=json.loads(a2)
```

Does not create any exceptions/error. Can someone please help me understand why the last comma in the first example is such a big issue and

how I could still convert the first example without modifying the data?

Comment: First example is not a valid JSON syntax. You can't parse it with a JSON parser that is compliant with the standard. Quick'n'dirty solution: run it through Python's ``eval`` instead of ``json.loads``.

Comment: You should really ask why is the data in 1 not clean. If you are consuming a webservice why is not sending you proper json etc.. Once you have established that you can look at various methods of cleaning it including the comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON syntax](http://json.org/) does not permit terminal commas, so the parser is correctly rejecting it.

As a side note, this syntax is not valid Javascript either. Some browsers will accept it, but they are acting outside the standard in doing so.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting that type of JSON back from my backend and I just wanted to make sure that I can still work with it.  Not sure how I can without actually changing the data (by removing the last comma).

Answer (score 1):

It is because your a1 JSON is invalid to being with:

From JSONLint:

```
Parse error on line 7:
..."value"    },    ]
--------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

The a2 JSON is valid, hence no exception.

**EDIT:**

Bogdan's 'quick n dirty' solution in the comments will allow you to mute the exception whilst retaining the same code